# iOS Developer s Program renewal

Tags: ios

I have developed an iPhone application, which is already inside iTunes available for download.
Apple also gives you access to the developers member area and many other tools.

Does anyone know, what happens if I decide not to renew ? Does this affect my existing app from download or function in existing devices? Which are the consequences ?

Comment: nothing will happen to the apps that have been downloaded by users. But it wont be available for download if you dont renew your developer program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [iOS program support center](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/program-renewals.html)

> What happens if I do not renew my iOS Developer Program membership?
>
> Once your membership expires, your apps will no longer be available on
>   the App Store and you will lose the ability to submit new apps. You
>   will lose access to pre-release software, the Apple Developer Forums,
>   Developer Technical Support, and the Certificate Utility. In addition,
>   your existing iOS Distribution certificates will be revoked and
>   invalidated. Finally, if you enrolled in the program as a company, you
>   will lose the ability to manage your development team.
>
> You will, however, retain your status as a Registered Apple Developer
>   and will have access to free development resources.

I think that says pretty much all, the users that downloaded your apps will still be able to use them I'm sure, but the apps will not be available on the store anymore.